# Quickly determine subclass based on abstract class

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a C++ base class CAbstrInstruction and a large number of direct subclasses:

```
class CAbstrInstruction { /* ... */ };

class CSleepInstruction: public CAbstrInstruction { /* ... */ };
class CSetInstruction: public CAbstrInstruction { /* ... */ };
class CIfInstruction: public CAbstrInstruction { /* ... */ };
class CWhileInstruction: public CAbstrInstruction { /* ... */ };
// ...
```

There is also a CScriptWorker that exposes a public method execute:

```
class CScriptWorker
{
    public:
        void execute (const CAbstrInstruction *pI);

    private:
        void doSleep (const CSleepInstruction *pI);
        void doSet (const CSetInstruction *pI);
        void doIf (const CIfInstruction *pI);
        void doWhile (const CWhileInstruction *pI);
        // ...
};
```

The implementation of the execute method currently looks like this:

```
void CScriptWorker::execute (const CAbstrInstruction *pI)
{
    const CSleepInstruction *pSleep =
        dynamic_cast<const CSleepInstruction *>(pI);

    if (pSleep != NULL)
    {
        doSleep (*pSleep);
        return;
    }

    const CSetInstruction *pSet =
        dynamic_cast<const CSetInstruction *>(pI);

    if (pSet != NULL)
    {
        doSet (*pSet);
        return;
    }

    const CIfInstruction *pIf =
        dynamic_cast<const CIfInstruction *>(pI);

    if (pIf != NULL)
    {
        doIf (*pIf);
        return;
    }

    const CWhileInstruction *pWhile =
        dynamic_cast<const CWhileInstruction *>(pI);

    if (pWhile != NULL)
    {
        doWhile (*pWhile);
        return;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

This is very clumsy and takes O(log(n)) to invoke the correct private method. Is there
any design pattern or language construct that simplifies this?

Clarification: I *could* move the private execute methods do... into the instruction
classes. The execute method would simply become:

```
    void execute (const CAbstrInstruction *pI) { pI->execute(); }
```

However, that's not what I want. Why not? **Separation of concerns**: The instances of CAbstrInstruction are just the description of what is do be done. They make up the Abstract Syntax Tree of the script. That's enough concern already. The CScriptWorker's concern is to actually do what's described by the instruction. CScriptWorker knows about the context the script is running in. CAbstrInstruction should not know about that.

Comment: take a look on visitor design pattern

Comment: You're right, I think that might solve the problem.

Comment: Your `CAbstrInstruction` provides nothing, what you're doing is equivalent to casting `void*`. What are the instructions supposed to provide as an interface?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Of course I've removed all the details inside the classes.

Comment: I meant, you are not using any meaningful features of inheritance/polymorphism, the code would work the same with casting `void*`, and that is never a good sign. What is `CAbstrInstruction` supposed to guarantee to the user?

Comment: dynamic_cast is type-safe. Casting void* is not. Besides, CAbstrInstruction provides the links from instruction to the next (not shown in the example).

Comment: It might be important to express what `CAbstrInstruction` is doing, seems like there is confusion on why it shouldn't have some virtual function `execute`

Comment: CAbstrInstruction are the instructions from an Abstract Syntax Tree, output from a parser. They contain all the information about the script. They do NOT implement the execute command, because that would make these classes very large. Besides, it would make them entangled with the context the script is running in. An AST should not do that. It should just provide the information needed to know what's to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the implementation of the `execute` method into the subclasses of `CAbstrInstruction` could be the answer if things were simple. However, the OP explicitly stated the `execute` method should be kept separate in a `CScriptWorker`, to separate the concern of knowing about *what* is to be done (the instructions' job) from *how* it is to be done (the `CScriptWorker`'s job). This may be achieved with **double dispatch**, also sometimes called the **visitor pattern**:

```
class IInstructionDispatchTarget
{
    public:
    virtual void onDispatch (const CSleepInstruction &instr) = 0;
    virtual void onDispatch (const CSetInstruction &instr) = 0;
};
class CAbstrInstruction
{
    public:
    virtual void dispatch (IInstructionDispatchTarget &t) const = 0;
};
class CSleepInstruction: public CAbstrInstruction
{
     public:
     virtual void dispatch (IInstructionDispatchTarget &t) const override
         { t.onDispatch (*this); }
};
class CSetInstruction: public CAbstrInstruction
{
     public:
     virtual void dispatch (IInstructionDispatchTarget &t) const override
         { t.onDispatch (*this); }
};
class CScriptWorker: public IInstructionDispatchTarget
{
    public:
    void execute (const CAbstrInstruction *pI)
        { pI->dispatch (*this); }
    virtual void onDispatch (const CSleepInstruction &instr) override
    {
        // do sleep
    }
    virtual void onDispatch (const CSetInstruction &instr) override
    {
        // do set
    }
};
```

When `execute` gets called on the `CScriptWorker`, it invokes the `dispatch` method of the instruction. In return, the instruction invokes the `onDispatch` method on the dispatch target, using its specific `this` pointer and thus invoking the correct method.

The interface `IInstructionDispatchTarget` serves two purposes. On the one hand, it makes sure the instances of `CAbstrInstruction` do not need to know the `CScriptWorker` at all; all they need to know is the interface. On the other hand, it allows other dispatch targets to use the same mechanism, e.g. when traversing the instructions to optimize the AST.

If the presence of `IInstructionDispatchTarget` is considered unnecessary, things can be slightly simplified as shown by the answer by ROX.

Comment: The introduction of the IInstructionVisitor interface here is useful if you have other classes that will derive from IInstructionVisitor. If not then it can be achieved with a slightly simpler version of double dispatch.

Comment: How would this simpler version look like?

Answer (score 1):

`CAbstrInstruction` should define a pure virtual method (`execute()` in your example), which your child classes should override and implement.

As an example:

```
class CAbstrInstruction 
{
     /* ... */
     virtual void execute() const = 0;
}

class CSleepInstruction 
{
     /* ... */
     void execute() override const
     {
         /* your code here */
     }
}

/* ... */
void CScriptWorker::execute (const CAbstrInstruction *pI)
{
    pI->execute();
}
```

Comment: If you had read the paragraph starting with "Clarification", you'd know that this is not what I want. The implementation of execute should not be in the instruction.

Comment: It is not IN the instruction. To oversimplify, you create a "placeholder" in the base class, which you "fill" in the child class.

Comment: Nope. Separation of concerns: Instruction should be just the description; execute should be in CScriptWorker.

Comment: The purpose of an abstract class is to **provide a common interface** and/or common behaviour across child classes. I having trouble seeing what your problem is here.

Comment: Look at your CScriptWorker class. It does nothing. It is not a worker at all. You've moved all the implementation to the instruction classes. It's not their concern.

Comment: Do you 100% need a "Worker" class? Doesn't a **CSetInstruction** already reveal the behaviour just by the name alone? Why the need to delegate its behaviour to a worker?

Comment: Think CAbstrInstruction as a recipe. CScriptWorker is the cook. Why should the recipe cook itself? The recipe's concern is to tell what is to be done. The cook's concern is to do it.

Comment: Inheritence of an abstract function doesn't violate sep of concerns. It defines an interface and if anything enhances concern separation. Search for Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: If you don't want to put a virtual method in CAbstrInstruction, you only resort is the visitor method, which is very cumbersome. Just use the virtual method solution, dude.

Comment: Think of unit testing. To unit test the parser and the instructions it creates, you'd have to instantiate the whole lot of objects needed to run the script even though you don't need them. If you've separated those concerns, unit testing becomes much easier. The visitor pattern is the way to go.

Comment: Another reason why composition should be preferred: The instructions are not supposed to change while the script is running, that's why `execute` takes a `const` instruction. In your design, `execute` itself needs to be `const`, and so you'd have to declare everything related to it as `mutable`, otherwise it can't do anything. `CScriptWorker`, otoh, doesn't have any such restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is best used when the client does not need to know the concrete type of an object. You want to use a [variant type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), since you have a fixed number of known instructions, and your executor needs to know which kind of instruction it is executing. It's easiest to use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), or [`boost::variant`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html) if you are pre-C++17.

```
#include <variant>

struct Set {};
struct If {};
struct While {};

using Instruction = std::variant<
    Set,
    If,
    While
    >;

#include <iostream>

struct Executor {
    void operator()(Set const&) const { std::cout << "Set\n"; }
    void operator()(If const&) const { std::cout << "If\n"; }
    void operator()(While const&) const { std::cout << "While\n"; }
};

void execute(Instruction const& i) {
    std::visit(Executor(), i);
}
```

Example:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    for (auto const& i : std::vector<Instruction>{While(), If(), Set()}) {
        execute(i);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
While
If
Set
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about std::variant. I'll have a look.

Comment: Hmm, apparently, a variant is not permitted to hold references or arrays. My instructions have both.

Comment: The variant can't hold references or arrays directly. They _can_ hold objects that contain references or arrays. You can wrap your instructions in `std::unique_ptr` if you need `Instruction` to be movable, or if you want to store them on the heap to reduce memory usage (the size of `std::variant` is determined by its largest alternative).

Comment: I think it could work, although I like the visitor pattern better.

Comment: I prefer `std::variant`, as it has less boilerplate and looser coupling. IMO, the visitor pattern is a workaround that is used in the absence of a proper variant type.

Answer (score 1):

The visitor pattern works well if you have other classes that will the implement IInstructionVisitor interface. That ensures all those classes can handle the same set of Instruction classes.

If you don't have additional classes deriving from IInstructorVisitor then you can simplify it slightly:-

```
class CScriptWorker
{
    public:
        void execute (const CAbstrInstruction* pI)
        {
           pI->ResolveInstructionType(*this);
        }

    // Can be made friends of appropriate instruction classes or left public as you see fit
       void doInstruction (const CSleepInstruction* pI);
       void doInstruction (const CSetInstruction* pI);
       void doInstruction (const CIfInstruction* pI);
       void doInstruction (const CWhileInstruction* pI);
    // note the name is now the same, name of the parameter should be enough to tell what's being done
    // also I'd probably make these references not pointers

};


class CAbstrInstruction
{
    public:
    virtual void ResolveInstructionType (CScriptWorker& v) = 0;
};


class CSleepInstruction: public CAbstrInstruction
{
     public:
     void ResolveInstructionType (CScriptWorker& w) override { w.doInstruction (this); }
};
```

The slight advantages of the simplification are, slightly less code now, slightly less code to modify if a new instruction is added, you can choose names other than visit, visitor etc.

Comment: doInstruction is private, CSleepInstruction can't invoke it.

Comment: Also, CSleepInstruction needs to know CScriptWorker, which is kind of ok, but not ideal.

Comment: I suppose that's another positive of using the visitor interface, ( although instructions would still need to know about that ). AbstractInstruction would only need a forward declaration of the worker class, not a full definition, but the derived classes would need to know about the doInstruction method.The visitor pattern is fine (although the visitor naming's not great in my opinion) I just present this an alternative, I'm not saying its better, there are pluses and minuses to both.

Comment: You're right, the naming wasn't great. I added an alternative naming to my answer.

Comment: I think the naming in the visitor pattern generally isn't that good, not just your version.